# Problem with web request when converting Javascript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, server-side

**[EDIT]**: I fixed it by installing cURL for PHP on my server.

I'm currently developing an API and have successfully implemented it using HTML and JavaScript. However, when I attempt to convert it to PHP for server-side processing, it doesn't seem to function properly. I need all requests to be handled server-side. I can't know what is wrong since I don't know how to access the php logs. When I make a POST request to the php page, I get a **500 Internal Server Error**.

My Html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Execute Command</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("form").submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                // Execute the shell command
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Speech_To_Text.php",
                    success: function (output) {
                        // Make the API request to Shuttle AI
                        var apiKey = "APIKEY";
                        var apiUrl = "https://api.shuttleai.app/v1/chat/completions";
                        var requestData = {
                            // model: "shuttle-1",
                            model: "shuttle-1",
                            internet: true,
                            messages: [
                                {
                                    role: "user",
                                    content: output
                                }
                            ]
                        };

                        // Send the request using fetch API
                        fetch(apiUrl, {
                            method: 'POST',
                            headers: {
                                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + apiKey,
                                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                            },
                            body: JSON.stringify(requestData)
                        })
                            .then(response => response.json())
                            .then(data => {
                                // Extract the content of the message
                                var messageContent = data.choices[0].message.content;
                                // Log the content in the console
                                console.log(messageContent);

                                // Make the audio generation request
                                var audioGenerationOptions = {
                                    method: 'POST',
                                    headers: {
                                        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + apiKey,
                                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                                    },
                                    body: JSON.stringify({
                                        input: messageContent,
                                        voice: 'thomas',
                                        model: 'eleven-labs'
                                    })
                                };

                                fetch('https://api.shuttleai.app/v1/audio/generations', audioGenerationOptions)
                                    .then(response => response.json())
                                    .then(audioResponse => {
                                        // Extract the content of the message
                                        var AudioURL = audioResponse.data.url;
                                        // Log the content in the console
                                        console.log(AudioURL);
                                    })
                            })
                            .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        console.error("Error:", error);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input type="submit" value="Execute Command">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

And the 'same but non-working code' in PHP:

```
<?php
// Ensure that the form is submitted
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $output = shell_exec("php Speech_To_Text.php");

    // Make the API request to Shuttle AI
    $apiKey = "APIKEY";
    $apiUrl = "https://api.shuttleai.app/v1/chat/completions";
    $requestData = array(
        "model" => "shuttle-1",
        "internet" => true,
        "messages" => array(
            array(
                "role" => "user",
                "content" => $output
            )
        )
    );

    // Send the request using cURL
    $ch = curl_init($apiUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($requestData));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $apiKey,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ));

    $apiResponse = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // Decode the API response
    $apiData = json_decode($apiResponse, true);

    // Extract the content of the message
    $messageContent = $apiData['choices'][0]['message']['content'];
    echo $messageContent;

    // Make the audio generation request
    $audioGenerationOptions = array(
        "input" => $messageContent,
        "voice" => "thomas",
        "model" => "eleven-labs"
    );

    $audioGenerationUrl = "https://api.shuttleai.app/v1/audio/generations";
    $audioGenerationOptions = json_encode($audioGenerationOptions);

    // Send the audio generation request using cURL
    $ch2 = curl_init($audioGenerationUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $audioGenerationOptions);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $apiKey,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ));

    $audioResponse = curl_exec($ch2);
    curl_close($ch2);

    // Decode the audio generation response
    $audioData = json_decode($audioResponse, true);

    // Extract the URL of the audio
    $audioUrl = $audioData['data']['url'];

    echo $audioUrl;
}
?>
```

When I make a POST request to the php page, I get a **500 Internal Server Error**. The only thing that seems to work is sending the $output as the response to the request. I think it might be a problem with how the request are made.

Comment: Could you setup a local php server, so you can have access to the logs while in development ? The logs are a critical part of your app and should always be accessible. There's no way to figure out what's wrong with your code without them.

Comment: "how to access the php logs" by checking your web server error logs, and/or by [enable displaying all errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display), note that the later suggestion is not recommended on prod env, enable it only in dev env

Comment: It's already all local, but how can I access the logs? I use Ubuntu Server

Comment: Check in `/var/logs` and then there will be a directory related to your webserver that should contain your error logs

Comment: I was able to find that :  undefined function curl_init()......

Comment: Sounds like your PHP was not installed with curl support

Comment: It seems to work after installing cURL! Next time, I'll check the logs! :)